# Gradlew Android Studio NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/cli/CommandLineParser

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, gradlew

When I try to run gradlew from the command line in Android Studio, I keep getting the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/cli/CommandLineParser
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.cli.CommandLineParser
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 1 more
```

I have done some research about this problem but the solutions I found did not solve mine. 
Another strange problem is that I cannot run gradle from the command line in Android studio. My gradle is the one that is bundled with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I did not set the GRADLE_HOME environment parameter. Since this parameter is not available, gradlew does not know where to find the gradle libraries. After setting this parameter and is able to run gradle in cmd, this problem disappers.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Can you please help me.

Comment: I'm suddenly facing this issue as well. Can you detail where we need to put in GRADLE_HOME?